# ASP.NET MVC Identity - Using internal User and Azure AD Authentication together

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

We are already running an ASP.NET MVC web application which is using internal users via token authentication. This is implemented in the standard way the ASP.NET MVC template provides.

Now we have a requirement to extend this authentication model and allow external Azure AD users to sign into the web application for configured tenant. I have figured out everything on the Azure AD side. Thanks to Microsoft's [Azure Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect) example.

Now both *individual account authentication* and *Azure AD* are working well independently. But they're not working together. When I insert both middleware together its giving issue.

Here's my startup_auth.cs file:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);


        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


        string ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"];            
        string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = ClientId,
            Authority = Authority,
            TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {                        
                ValidateIssuer = false,
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {                            
                    string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;                         
                    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },                        
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    // retriever caller data from the incoming principal
                    string issuer = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("iss").Value;
                    string UPN = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
                    string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;

                    if (
                        // the caller comes from an admin-consented, recorded issuer
                        (db.Tenants.FirstOrDefault(a => ((a.IssValue == issuer) && (a.AdminConsented))) == null)
                        // the caller is recorded in the db of users who went through the individual onboardoing
                        && (db.Users.FirstOrDefault(b =>((b.UPN == UPN) && (b.TenantID == tenantID))) == null)
                        )
                        // the caller was neither from a trusted issuer or a registered user - throw to block the authentication flow
                        throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();                            
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                    context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This configuration works well for local user accounts but doesn't work for AAD. To enable AAD authentication, I need to configure the `UseCookieAuthentication` part as shown below, which will break my local user account authentication.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });
```

Basically I need to remove the local users middleware to get AAD work.

What I mean by AAD not working is, I am not able to go to any secured action which is protected by the `[Authorize]` attribute. It's calling the `SecurityTokenValidated` event, and I am able to get all AAD claims and able to validate against my custom tenant. But when I redirect to root of my app (which is a secured action) at the end, it throws me back to my custom login page. Seems it's not internally signing in the user and not creating the necessary authentication cookies.

I would appreciate any ideas on what I could be missing here.

Thanks

Comment: I am testing it using the code above, it works well for me. Since you mentioned that your web app was using token authentication, and after you enable the Azure Active Directory authentication, it break the individual account authentication. Can you please describe about how you implement the individual accounts authentication? Based on my understanding, the individual accounts authentication also use the cookie authentication by default.

Comment: So I already had individual user account enabled in my application with same we as default MVC template provides. With code above which enables Azure AD authentication, individual accounts working fine. But Azure AD is not working. Azure AD triggers SecurityTokenValidated event where i can get all the user claims, but at the end when i redirect to root of application which is secured action, it returns back 401. Only when I set up app.UseCookieAuthentication with blank option my Azure AD works fine, but that breaks individual account case.

Comment: Since the code works well for me, suspect the issue may caused by other code. I have upload the code sample [here](https://github.com/VitorX/webapp-aad-localaccount). If you still have the problem, you may share a runnable code sample to help to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this sample my end. will update you.

Comment: thanks @FeiXue-MSFT. Your example worked for me. I was missing some wire up in account controller. Only question i have, when you log out from app signed in by azure, app redirects to azure screen for log out and redirect back to application login page. This clears probably all azure cookies and next time you login it asks you azure credential again. But in this sample we are not getting this behaviour. After logout if we login again, we are in without entering credentials. Is there a way to configure other behaviour?

Comment: To sign-out the web app if users login from Azure AD, we also need to sign-out using the OWIN component. I am trying summarizing this issue in the post and update the code sample, please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support both individual accounts and other account from social data provider, only need to add them using OWIN component.

And to sign-out the users which login from Azure AD, we need to sign-out both the cookie issued from web app and Azure AD. First, I modified the `ApplicationUser` class to add the custom claim to detect whether the users login from Azure AD or individual accounts like below.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        if((this.Logins as System.Collections.Generic.List<IdentityUserLogin>).Count>0)
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("idp", (this.Logins as System.Collections.Generic.List<IdentityUserLogin>)[0].LoginProvider));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Then we can change the `LogOff` method to support sign-out from Azure AD to clear the cookies from Azure AD:

```
// POST: /Account/LogOff
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{

    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    var idpClaim = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => { return claim.Type == "idp"; });
    if (idpClaim!=null)
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helped.

Comment: Do you have a list of things that you did on Azure side?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your OpenID Connect auth is not connecting to your Cookie auth.  It looks like you need to specify a `SignInAsAuthenticationType` in your `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` that matches the `AuthenticationType` in your `CookieAuthenticationOptions` or your `ExternalCookie` auth type.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: tried setting SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
which is same as AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie.

But no change in behavior. Still getting 401 from secured action.